# Implementing a complex function in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

In Matlab's command window I obtained several equations which look like:

```
Tc1 = (- 2*J2*cos(t3)*sin(t1)*sin(t3)*n^2 + 2*J2*w3*sin(t3)*n)/cos(t2) - d2 + cos(t2)*(J2*cos(t3)*sin(t1)*sin(t3)*n^2 + J2*v3*sin(t1)) + J1*w1*w3 + J2*w1*w3 - J3*w1*w3 + J2*v2*cos(t1) + J2*n^2*cos(t1)*tan(t2) - J2*w2^2*cos(t1)*tan(t2) + 2*J2*w3^2*cos(t1)*tan(t2) + J2*w2^2*cos(t1)^3*tan(t2) - J2*w3^2*cos(t1)^3*tan(t2) - 2*J2*n*w2*cos(t3)*tan(t2) + 2*J2*w2*w3*sin(t1)*tan(t2) - J2*n^2*cos(t1)*cos(t3)^2*tan(t2) + 2*J2*n*w2*cos(t1)^2*cos(t3)*tan(t2) - 2*J2*w2*w3*cos(t1)^2*sin(t1)*tan(t2) - 2*J2*n*w3*cos(t1)*cos(t3)*sin(t1)*tan(t2)
```

In Simulink I use From and Goto blocks for all the parameters (Tc1, J1, J2, J3, t1, t2, t3 and so on).

Now I am wondering what the easiest way is to implement these long formulas in Simulink for a simulation. Normally I would just rebuild the equations using all kind of blocks in Simulink, but the equations I ended up with this time are much longer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. the first way is using `Fcn` block from user-defined function and just write your function in one line and use inputs like `u(1)`,`u(2)`,....

The `Fcn` block applies the specified mathematical expression to its input. The expression can include one or more of these components:

- `u` — The input to the block. If `u` is a vector, `u(i)` represents
  the i-th element of the vector; `u(1)` or `u` alone represents the
  first element.
- Numeric constants.
- Arithmetic operators (`+` `-` `*`   `/` `^`).
- Relational operators (`==` `!=` `>` `<` `>=` `<=`) — The
  expression returns `1` if the relation is true; otherwise, it returns
  `0`.
- Logical operators (`&&` `||` `!`) — The expression returns `1`
  if the relation is true; otherwise, it returns `0`.
- Parentheses.
- Mathematical functions — `abs`, `acos`, `asin`, `atan`, `atan2`,
  `ceil`, `cos`, `cosh`, `exp`, `fabs`, `floor`, `hypot`, `ln`, `log`,
  `log10`, `pow`, `power`, `rem`, `sgn`, `sin`, `sinh`, `sqrt`, `tan`,
  and `tanh`.

check this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/fcn.html)

---

2. The second way is using `Matlab Function` from user-defined function and write all the functions you have in an embedded `m-file`. and then connect all inputs and outputs to it.

check this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html)

Comment: I have implemented the second method and it works fine, thanks a lot!